# Error When passing data between components

Tags: reactjs, components, state, prop

I am trying to pass a value from one component - Counters.jsx to Counter.jsx. When I go to the developer console and I do a log, I can get the data from: this.props.value but when I try to set this into the state, I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

```
// This is the component: Counters

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
  { id: 1, value: 4 },
  { id: 2, value: 0 },
  { id: 3, value: 0 },
  { id: 4, value: 0 }
  ]
};

render() {
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
      <Counter key={counter.id} value={counter.value} selected={true} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
}
}



// This is the component: Counter

import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: this.props.value
  };
```

The issue is in the class Counter when I set the state - Count to this.props.value. However this value is accessible if I do console.log(this.props.value).

I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Does anyone know if I missed out something and why is it that I can access it with console.log but cannot set the state count to this.props.value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with cases where there is no `props.value` for some reason.

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: this.props.value || 0,
  };
...
}
```

In your case, I think you don't have to use another `state`value.
It is better to use the `props` variable directly rather than using the `state` variable.

Comment: I don't think so, please check this. https://codepen.io/minion/pen/VJMZbb

Comment: Use default props for such case

Comment: This will work correctly with -1 because it is saying pass 0 when there is a false ( 0,null,false ) value but -1 is a true value.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: props.value,
    };
}
```

Comment: @avinitish666: you need to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if its working for you!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Did it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default values in constructor and update state in componentDidUpdate method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   this.setState({count : this.props.value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you missed was passing props to super in constructor.

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props); 
  this.state = { count:this.props.value, }; 
}
```

You cannot use this.props in constructor without passing it to super.

Also, as one of the answer which says you need to handle cases when there is no prop passed.

I suggest you to use default props for such case.

Check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for understanding default props and prop types.

Answer (score 0):

Change your component code to this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: this.props.value
    };
  };
```

You are trying to use `this` without providing it a proper context. Change your code as i suggested and it should work just fine.
Hope it   helps!!